# Me salta error en el button click listener

Tags: java, android-studio, botón, nullpointerexception, null

hice una app de mandar mail aparte y estoy intentando implementarla dentro de otra app, bien pues me da este error
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference`

este es mi codigo

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment  {

//public EditText mEmail;
public EditText mSubject;
public EditText mMessage;
private Button buttonSend_contact;

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public ContactFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment ContactFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static ContactFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);

    mMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.messageID);
    mSubject = view.findViewById(R.id.subjectID);

    buttonSend_contact =  view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSendMail);

    buttonSend_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendMail();
        }
    });




    return view;
}
private void sendMail() {

    String mail = "turespawnofficial@gmail.com";
    String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
    String subject = mSubject.getText().toString().trim();

    //Send Mail
    JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(getActivity(),mail,subject,message);

    javaMailAPI.execute();

}
```

este es mi xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ContactFragment">

<!-- <EditText
    android:id="@+id/mailID"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Email"/> -->

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/subjectID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Subject" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/messageID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Message" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSendMail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi error fue tipografico, me confundi al poner en el inflater un layout que no es, en vez de poner fragment_vides debi poner fragment_contact, por lo demas el codigo funciona perfectamente